# Как исправить тавтологию и стилистику в данном контексте?

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика, тавтология

Как исправить тавтологию ( если она есть) и стилистику в данном отрывке? 
На каждой из арок был вырезан символ. На южной арке - треугольник,  обращенный вершиной вверх, на восточной - такой же, но с ровной линией посередине. Западную арку отличал треугольник, смотрящий вниз, а северную- такой же, как и на западной арке, но с линией посередине.
P.S. уместно ли тире в предложениях?

Answer (score 2):

Символы были вырезаны на каждой из арок, сориентированных по сторонам света. На южной — треугольник, обращенный вершиной вверх, на восточной и северной — такой же, только с ровной линией посередине, вершина треугольника западной арки смотрела вниз.

*На **каждой** из арок был вырезан **свой** символ* (из ответа Alex_andera). — Так писать логически неверно, потому что на двух арках имеются одинаковые символы.

Comment: Ваш ответ мне понравился больше. Вот только на слове "смотрела" в самом конце я спотыкаюсь. Я бы выбрал настоящее время — "смотрит" (ср. "обращённый" в начале) или, ещё лучше, заменил бы на "направлена".

Comment: Римма Михайлова, спасибо большое. Вы прекрасно всё описали и объяснили. Только я допустила неточность. На южной арке - треугольник, обращенный вершиной вверх, на восточной - такой же, но с ровной линией посередине. Западную арку отличал треугольник, смотрящий вниз, а северную - такой же, как на западной арка, но с линией посередине.

Comment: Римма Михайлова, как вам такой вариант: На каждой из арок, сориентированных по сторонам света, были вырезаны треугольники. На южной- треугольник, обращенный вершиной вверх, восточную украшал такой же, только с ровной линией посередине. Вершина западного  треугольника была направлена вниз. Тот, что был на северной, повторял его, но тоже имел линию посередине. Написала на основе ваших правок и комментариев...

Comment: @Римма Михайлова "Свой" указывает на _принадлежность_ одного символа одной арке, а не на уникальность его в сравнении с другими. Могли быть и символы, общие для двух или более арок (в виде объединительной скобы и т. п.). В варианте же "символы" количество таковых на одной арке остаётся неясным до прочтения второго предложения.

Comment: Рассуждаем, смотрим: СВОЙ —  4. Своеобразный, свойственный **только кому-, чему-л. одному, данному или единому.** (http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9&all=x)  Другие значения по смыслу не подходят. P. S. После правки предложения это уже неважно, ведь теперь у автора все треугольники разные.

Comment: Нарочка, если Вы хотите обратиться к кому-то персонально, то необходимо указать собачку с ником (без пробела): @РиммаМихайлова. Иначе Ваши сообщения до адресата (то есть до меня) не добираются. Я поначалу тоже ошибалась.

Answer (score 2):

***Смотрел, украшал, был направлен...***

Выбор лексики должен соответствовать общему стилю текста (научное или художественное описание). Можно убрать  тавтологию, поправить стилистику, но не стоит забывать  об информативности текста (максимум информации при минимуме слов). Читатель должен видеть символы, ясно представлять их, но вот слов в тексте много, а общая картина остается неясной.

**Вариант правки**

*На каждой из арок был вырезан символ в виде треугольника, при этом его вершина была направлена вверх на южной и восточной арке и вниз – на западной и северной. Кроме того, треугольники северной и восточной арок имели ровную линию посередине, так что все четыре символа  различались между собой.*

Comment: да, вы абсолютно правы: теперь всё читается безупречно...

Answer (score 1):

Да, при таком количестве однотипных элементов описания есть смысл разнообразить связанные с ними глаголы. Количество тире (хотя грамматически они и обоснованы) можно сократить добавлением пропущенных слов. Например:

> На каждой из арок был вырезан свой символ. На южной  - треугольник,
>   обращенный вершиной вверх, восточную украшал такой же, но с ровной
>   линией посередине. Треугольник на западной арке смотрел вниз, а тот,
>   что на северной, повторял треугольник на восточной.

Comment: Спасибо, Alex_ander. Я тоже думала, как разнообразить данный текст, чтобы предотвратить тавтологию, но для это нужен писательский талант, как у вас. А он у меня, к сожалению, отсутствует....